# WordPress - Child Theme not overriding the Parent's CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

I have a child theme set up. I have a plugin WP-SCSS, I set directories and when I, I think, refresh the page, or maybe it's on save, but somehow the SCSS compiles to CSS. Great, but the issue is the css is not overriding the styles from the parent.

I'm using the bought theme Unicon. I am not sure why this is causing me issues, I don't want to have to keep writing `!important` on everything.

This is my `style.css` file:

```
/*
Theme Name: Unicon Child Theme
Description: Unicon Child Theme for your Customizations
Author: minti
Template: unicon
Version: 1.0
*/
@import url("css/main.css");
@import url("../unicon/style.css");
```

And my functions.php

```
<?php
function cls_scripts() {
    // wp_enqueue_style( 'cls-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cls_scripts' );
```

I'm not sure if it's the SCSS plugin causing this, worst case scenario I just don't use SASS and write everything into my `style.css`, thoughts?

Comment: Are you seeing your compiled css in dev tools?  Is it compiling correctly?

Comment: @jmargolisvt Yeah it's compiling, I see it when I inspect, but it's being overwritten by other css files from the parent theme